# C++ Are child classes of the same type as themselves AND their parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, instanceof

After a semester without C++ but plenty of Java i now i have a lot of new questions.

Given `class baseClass` and `class childClass : public baseClass` definitions and, let's say, the instances `baseClass bClass(); childClass cClass();`, in a Java equivalent context (though in C++) would `cClass instanceof bClass` be `true`?

And, if so(now on polymorphism), would a function `add(baseClass &left, baseClass &right)` be able to expect ANY of the `baseClass`'s children as the `left` and/or `right`?

I supose the last question may be misleading, but it still depends on the first one being true, so if needed i'll expand more on that afterwards.

Thank you!

Comment: The answer to all your questions is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would cClass instanceof bClass be true?

Yes

> would a function add(baseClass &left, baseClass &right) be able to expect ANY of the baseClass's children as the left and/or right?

Yes. This is called `upcasting` (because you are moving up the hierarchy) and is the concept behind runtime polymorphism in C++. Consider the example below

```
class A
{
public:
  func()
  {
    cout << "A";
  }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  func()
  {
    cout << "B";
  }
};

void foo(A &obj)
{
  obj.func();
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  foo(a);

  cout << endl;

  foo(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A 
B
```

We can safely supply reference to child class object to a function expecting a reference to base class object because whatever exists in base class will exist in child class.

Comment: Beautiful. Straight forward answer with example, could not have been more clear. Thank you.